# chrome.tabs.executeScript runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey I have a Chrome extension and I need to stop page given from loading (before it starts).

So we have the following code in background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function (e){
    // Important! there's more code that make sure this runs once - it isn't recuresive
    killPage(e.tab);
});

function killPage(tabId){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        code: "window.stop();",
        runAt: "document_start"
    });
}
```

When we use window.stop, the execute script happens twice, and when we use 
`document.open();document.close()` it runs endless times and reaches max callstack.

We made sure that the only thing that runs again is the code in the execute script (not event the line `chrome.tabs.executeScript`)

How can I make the execute script run only once?

Comment: Looks like you cut out code that's essential to your question.

Comment: Also, please explain better what you're _trying_ to do, this looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Xan The question looks quite complete to me, what part is missing according to you?

Comment: @RobW Well, if the problem is code being run multiple times, and _"more code that make sure this runs once"_ is cut out, that looked like a problem to me. It's good you could diagnose it without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has already been fixed in Chrome 41 - [crbug.com/431263](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=431263).

It only occurs at `document_start`, so if you use `document_end` or `document_idle`, then the bug doesn't get triggered (but the script will be activated later).

It only happens with synchronous (blocking) code. If you can use asynchronous APIs, then you can achieve the desired effect without hitting the bug. For instance:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    // Use setTimeout to work around crbug.com/431263
    code: "setTimeout(function() { window.stop(); }, 0);",
    runAt: "document_start"
});
```